# Avoid CSS floats at different levels in the hierarchy interfering

Tags: css, css-float

Note: the sample markup here is grossly simplified for clarity. I've put a still simplified but less so version on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9HLXK/7/).

I have a two-column layout which works by giving the primary column a large margin and floating the secondary column into it. Both columns can contain multiple boxes; the simplified markup is

```
<div style="width:940px">
    <div style="float:left; width:282px">Secondary box A</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:282px">Secondary box B</div>
    <div style="margin-left:320px; width:602px">Primary box A</div>
    <div style="margin-left:320px; width:602px">Primary box B</div>
</div>
```

I now want to put a few paragraphs of text into primary box A and an image, floating it right:

```
<div style="width:940px">
    <div style="float:left; width:282px">Secondary box A</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:282px">Secondary box B</div>
    <div style="margin-left:320px; width:602px">
        <img style="width:215px; height:180px; float:right" ... />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:320px; width:602px">Primary box B</div>
</div>
```

But to my surprise the floating image is being forced down to the final secondary box.

Is there some way to isolate the floats inside the div from the floats outside it? Or am I going to have to wrap the secondary boxes in one div and the primary boxes in another and find a suitable two-column layout which doesn't float the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell you the truth, I was as surprized as you were - and I'm not sure what is happening in your example. It appears that .secondary0 is affecting the ypos of the first .fakeimg - which doesn't make any sense to me, especially since .secondary1 does not affect its ypos.

Anyway, I did find a fix - by wrapping the secondaries into an extra div (so they are in a proper, completely separated box) - and added the float to this wrapper:

http://jsfiddle.net/9HLXK/8/

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for taking so long to get round to checking this out properly. The fix works when applied to the non-simplified version as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the `.leftColumn` `div`s with a `div` and giving it: `float:left; clear:left;`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9HLXK/9/)

Comment: well - isn't that exactly the same answer as mine?